# Разбухает БД Access после использования модуля

Tags: база-данных, access, vba

Есть БД, которая весит 1гб и в ней 1 миллион записей.
При использовании модуля, который идет сверху вниз и обновляет поле, которое имеет тип Тест(255), база разбухает до 2 гб и повреждается.
Можно ли это предотвратить?
Сам модуль по сути просто обновляет поле по определенным условиям.

Comment: Хорошо бы в подобных вопросах указывать версии используемой СУБД Access и ОС.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему, речь идет об Access 2010 у которой есть [документированый лимит на максимальный размер базы](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854), равный 2Gb.

При этом важно помнить, что в эти 2Gb помимо данных входят еще и метаданные (то есть служебные объекты, индексы, и пр). Во время исполнения запроса или сортировки записей, все эти оверхэды (*служебные объекты*) хранятся в том же .accdb-файле.

Как только размер БД достигает 2Gb + 1 байт, база повреждается.
Это поведение согласно дизайну и **предотвратить его нельзя**.

Исходя из сказанного в предыдущей строке, лично для меня Access является СУБД базового уровня (для начинающих). На Access'е можно потренироваться писать простейшие запросы и хранить в нем кулинарные рецепты. Но для серьёзных проектов я бы убедительно рекомендовал уходить с Access на самых ранних стадиях. Отличная кандидатура - SQL Server Express Edition.

**UPDATE**
Access/Jet не используют транзакций и стало быть лога тарнзакций тоже не ведет. Немного подробностей здесь: [SO: Do we have transactions in MS-Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078432/do-we-have-transactions-in-ms-access)

Подходящие ресурсы по проблеме (англ.):

- [What causes a database file size to bloat (file size increase)?](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=48759)
- [Growing MS Access File Size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450995/growing-ms-access-file-size-problem)

> *Access uses 2K pages to store data. The database is expanded as needed to create these 2K pages for storing data. If a page is
>   completely emptied the page is marked as FREE and added to a FREE LIST
>   that access checks for storing data (reuse). If the FREE LIST is empty
>   (or some lower limit unknown to me), Access grabs more space and
>   creates FREE pages. FREE pages are not returned to the OS for reuse
>   (reclaimed). Only compacting the DB will restore the FREE pages to the
>   OS. Of course a Compact is really a copy of the DB rather than a
>   release of the FREE PAGES. Once compacted Access leaves some FREE
>   pages (I have not seen how many) and if you use them up, it adds
>   more.*

Если поверхностно взглянуть на эти и другие посты, то в них не приводятся каких-либо конкретных причин (конкретнее чем циатата выше), а обреченно констатируется факт, что движок Jet - это архаизм и поэтому разработчики вынуждены выдумывать различные хаки как делать базу компактной и принудительно высвобождать 2k-страницы.

Если честно, то это настолько суровое и неблагодарное занятие, что поиск дальнейших решений по защите от роста базы следует прекратить. Вместо этого следует сконцентрироваться на портировании Access/VB-кода на годную, современную СУБД. К сожалению, на портирование придется потратить время и ресурсы, так как Access использует принципиально иные подходы к программированию. Диалект SQL у него тоже, увы, проприетарный.

На конкретный вопрос, думаю, мне удалось ответить однозначно.

Comment: Про критический вес в 2 гб я знаю. Просто интересно почему банально обновление 1 колонки через модуль повышает вес базы до критической. Может можно как-то уменьшить побочное разбухание при выполнении модуля? У меня сейчас реализовано так: Переменной типа recordset я присваиваю OpenRecordSet("Таблица"), потом в цикле While NOT rst.EOF делают 'rst.edit rst("field").value=val rst.update'

Comment: Не знаю точно каким образом базы Jet/Access ведут лог транзакций, но то что они его ведут - это бесспорно. Думаю, что база "разбухает" именно из-за того, что в файл .accdb пишутся все еще не закомиченые транзакции. Не возьмусь это утвержать, но выглядит все именно так. UPD: Оказывется лог не ведётся :) /серьёзные данные там хранить нельзя/

Comment: Стоп! Research продолжается. Движок Jet лог не ведёт. http://www.recovery.compactaccessdatabase.org/

Comment: @iluxa1810 дополнил ответ.

Comment: Мда, даже и не думал, что это настолько плохая субд. Спасибо, будет чем аргументировать ее осуждение.

Comment: Jet не удаляет из файла старые данные при удалении строк. Возможно, такой же эффект при изменении колонок какого-то определённого типа. Удаление старых данных делается операцией Compact/Repair.